# pyaudio change the number of samples of calling the callback function

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I want to do a simple realtime processing to audio every 4096 samples. But this code calls the callback function every 1024 samples. I just want to change the frame_count to 4096.

```
import pyaudio
import time

WIDTH = 2
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    out=do_something(in_data)
    print(frame_count)#1024
    return (out, pyaudio.paContinue)

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(0.1)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

Comment: have you tried changing the rate to a higher value (like times it by 4)

Comment: @acutesoftware Yes, I have change it higher and lower, but it just change the time it takes to call the callback function it does not change the number of samples passed to the callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but from the documentation it seems that if you change the stream open line to:

```
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=4096,
                stream_callback=callback)
```

that you should get your required number of samples per block. The frames_per_buffer defaults at 1024 so that's probably why you're getting this value in your test.

Good luck!